# Adding elements in an array. Thread/simulator issues?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, types, ios-simulator

I am attempting to take an array called _operationArray that has NSNumbers stored within it. I want to take the last two elements of the array and add them together. In the following code, endObject should be the last element space in the array, secondToEndObject should be the second to last element space. I then attempt to add those two elements together. There are no errors or warnings but when I try to run it in the simulator and press the button, the simulator closes and xcode opens and says stuff about threads (which I don't understand).

```
- (IBAction)addition:(id)sender {

NSUInteger endObject = [_operationArray count];
NSUInteger secondToEndObject = [_operationArray count] - 2;
NSUInteger firstNumber =[[_operationArray objectAtIndex:endObject] integerValue] ;
NSUInteger secondNumber = [[_operationArray objectAtIndex:secondToEndObject] integerValue];
_theResult = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:((signed)(firstNumber + secondNumber))];
```

}

Like I said, I don't really understand the issue, so if any other information is necessary to solve this please let me know. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Image of error: http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/gmc4i1qcq1i7eihesndgdn5q92_screen-shot-2014-04-13-at-11.39.14-am.png

Comment: Two issues (index & the check if there are at least 2 elements) pointed by @Leonardo Bernardini, are corrects. But please, show the error message (about threads).

Comment: If you can't copy/paste them, look how to take screenshots on a Mac.

Comment: Ok, on the "box" at the center bottom, click on the panel in grey, near the one in blue, you should be able to see the logged error.

Comment: out of curiosity, do ANY programs run on your simulator? almost wonder from the error if you need to reinstall it...

Comment: Please see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to work with the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[_operationArray count]` is wrong, you're workig with base 0 indexes, that means the last item is `[_operationArray count]-1;`

Also you should always check if 
`[_operationArray count] >= 2` to avoid crashes

Comment: about the crash, you probably are getting a EXC BAD ACCESS in your main thread, that means you're reading / accessing an unitialized memory block

Comment: Thank you very much, but that doesn't seem to have solved the issue. Leonardo, how would I fix this EXC BAD ACCESS?

Comment: are you sure you have NSNumber* pointers in the array ? Put a breakpoint and inspect it before getting the objects..

Comment: Okay I'm adding the breaking point and if statements to check this, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this seems closer to what you want.

```
- (IBAction)addition:(id)sender {
  // You said the array holds NSNumbers, so that's what you are getting out of it
  NSNumber *lastNumber = _operationArray.lastObject;
  NSNumber *penultimateNumber = _operationArray[_operationArray.count - 2];

  NSNumber *_theResult = @(lastNumber.integerValue + penultimateNumber.integerValue);
}
```

Comment: It's going to be hard for anyone to know that without seeing more information about the crash or error

Comment: Based on the original code you posted, it seems like you may be confused about some aspects of Objective-C, so the problem could be coming from somewhere outside of this method.

Comment: @user3527434 try adding exception breakpoint. That way you will see where exactly your code crashes. http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions